# Flutter_Console every command just freezes and does not return anything

Tags: flutter

I have tried Flutter Doctor, creating an app, checking what channel I am on, even switching channels.The only thing that happens is what is in the screenshot below. I see the command and get no response on the next line and instead only a blinking cursor.[image: image of the console with no response where I only receive blinking cursor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I just copied the files from inside of the zip and didn't extract them first, after extracting them it is now working.